# Compare $A$ and $B$

Tags: number-comparison

Compare $A$ and $B$ with:
$$A = \sqrt{2017} + \sqrt{2019} + \sqrt{2023}$$
$$B = \sqrt{2018} + \sqrt{2020} + \sqrt{2021}$$
I tried to prove $A^4 < B^4$ but it's too hard to do that.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Nguyen, could you write your attempts and efforts in your post?

Answer (score 1):

Well its enough to prove
$$A < B$$
since taking power to a positive number is operation that does not change sign. Easy to prove seems
$$A^2 < B^2$$
just by doing all of that products.

Quick guess without calculator would be also to use Taylor series
$$\sqrt{2017 + x} \approx \sqrt{2017} + \frac{x}{2\sqrt{2017}} - \frac{1}{8}\frac{x^2}{2017^{3/2}} $$
so only third term makes difference and you effectively want to compare $x^2$
$$2^2+6^2 > 1^2 + 3^2 + 4^2$$
so that
$$40 > 26$$
seems to hold.

Comment: In the same spirit : replace $2017$ by $x$ and use Taylor series for infintely large $x$ to get $$A-B=-\frac{7}{4 x^{3/2}}\left( 1-\frac{33}{7 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Thank you but I had done it already. I use the subtraction of A and B; it seems easier than yours.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.